# How to apply a categorized list to a large dataset in excel or R

Tags: r, excel, categories

I have an excel sheet with one column being a long list ranging from about 201-960. In a second column I have that list categorized where 1-6 values of the list are put into a category.

Secondly, I have a large dataset in excel (12,000+ column length) where a row has a value from the first column, but I would like to apply the category to this dataset. I am aware of the IF() function in excel, but my dataset is too large to use this method.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KpXQ.png)

[Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nozGZ.png)

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please give us some context to your question. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints. It's a good start to give some data, make a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and give an example of your desired output. And data as screenshots... well...https://xkcd.com/2116/

Comment: Maybe `match(Dataset$col, Categories$col)`. This will work if the values in the `Dataset`'s column are all in the `Categories`' column.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you want to merge two data.frames using a given column. I made a small example:

```r
dt1 <- data.frame(Strat=1:5, StratDesc=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
dt2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5), Strat=1:5)

merge(dt2, dt1, by=c("Strat"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, except it removed a few rows from my datset. I guess some things didnt match up.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). :-)